# BASH shell script not looping correctly

Tags: bash

I am putting together a shell script to download application logs based on some functions. The scenario is as follows:

1. The initial log file has been downloaded with a separate function not covered here. This is the basis for reading the initial **nextSkip** value.
2. The initial log file is scanned for a **nextEndDate** and **nextSkip** fields and then assigned to ENDT and SKP variables.
3. I then am performing a curl command loop such that I continue to download the logs until ENDT is empty (this means there are no logs to process further). When writing the logfile to disk I perform a word count and then append the resulting number to the log file (done incrementally).
4. I use cat since the log file limit is very small (100 entries per download)

The problem I have is that when I run the script, the following files are generated. When I execute the script again, the applogs function is called and
although it looks like it has used the nextSkip from the "previous"  applog-1.log file, it looks like it's overwriting it with the new logs and nextSkip value
and does not increment the file value as well. So in effect it looks like it only runs once and overwrites the applog-1.log.

applog-0.log
applog-1.log

I was expecting it loop through the variable state, download the logs, use the nextEndDate from that to pull the next lot, and so on but not the case.
I'm missing something daft here :(

Any suggestions welcomed

Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash
STARTDT=2022-01-31T00:01:00.619Z
 
 .
 .
 .
 
applogs()
{
  OUTDIR=/tmp/app_logs
  MAXLOGFILE=$(ls $OUTDIR | sort -n | tail -1)
  ENDT=$(cat $OUTDIR/$MAXLOGFILE | awk -F'nextEndDate' '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/"//g' -e 's/://' -e  's/}//g' -e 's/,nextSkip:.*//')
  SKP=$(cat $OUTDIR/$MAXLOGFILE | awk -F'nextSkip' '{print $2}' | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/://' |  sed 's/}//g')

  if [ -z "$SKP" ]
    then
      DSKP=2
      else
       SSKP=$(cat $OUTDIR/$MAXLOGFILE | awk -F'nextSkip' '{print $2}' | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/://' |  sed 's/}//g')
  fi


  while [ -n "$ENDT" ] || [ -z "$SSKP" ]  # Check if nextenddate is not empty and skip is empty
   do
    curl --request GET \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
    "https://URL/logs?start_date=$STARTDT&end_date=$ENDT&skip=$SKP&limit=100" > $OUTDIR/applog-`ls applog-* | wc -l`*.log

     if [ -n "$ENDT" ] || [ -n $DSKP ]      # explictly set next enddate condition and default skip
       then
         curl --request GET \
         --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
         "https://URL/logs?start_date=$STARTDT&end_date=$ENDT&skip=$DSKP&limit=100" > $OUTDIR/applog-`ls applog-* | wc -l`*.log
     fi
     break
     done
}

applogs
```

Comment: What's the point of setting a value for `SSKP` by re-doing the computation that got you `SKP`, instead of just doing `SSKP=$SKP`?  Or even `SSKP=`, since you already know that `SKP` has an empty value at that point?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not accept that the code presented behaves as you describe.  Nothing inside the loop changes anything affecting the loop condition, so, barring an error that causes the script to terminate pematurely, that loop will iterate indefinitely, downloading the content of the same URLs to new names each time.

Comment: And speaking of errors, you're not watching for or handling them, but you should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script needed another variable assignment at the end of the if statement so that MAXLOGFILE is assigned the incremental max logfile number.

```
...

  while [ -n "$ENDT" ] || [ -z "$SSKP" ]  # Check if nextenddate is not empty and skip is empty
   ...
     fi
     
    MAXLOGFILE=$(ls -Art $OUTDIR | tail -1)
    ENDT=$(cat $OUTDIR/$MAXLOGFILE | awk -F'nextEndDate' '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/"//g' -e 's/://' -e  's/}//g' -e 's/,nextSkip:.*//')
    SKP=$(cat $OUTDIR/$MAXLOGFILE | awk -F'nextSkip' '{print $2}' | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/://' |  sed 's/}//g')

  if [ ! -n $NEXTENDT ]; then
     echo "Eng of Logs - No more EndDates detected"
     break
  fi

    done
}
```